# How do I assign the result of an SQL query executed in JDBC to a java variable?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a student table with columns email, password, and a variable Result which can either hold a value "pass" or "fail". I'm executing this statement first in java using JDBC to find the result of a particular student when their email is passed.

```
String sql = "SELECT result FROM hr.student WHERE email = '"+email+"'";

conn = getConnection();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

The value returned will either be "pass" or "fail". I want to store the returned value in a variable to use it for an if-else statement. 
(if result is "pass", 
  --statements-- 
else 
  --statements--)

How do I do this?

Comment: Oracle has Tutorials on that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html I guess, you'll find them helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to create the prepared statement as follows:

```
String sql = "SELECT result FROM hr.student WHERE email = ?";
conn = getConnection();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1,email)
```

and then proceed as shown above

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
String result = null;
if (rs.next()) { // replace 'if' with 'while' to iterate if multiple records
    result = rs.getString("result");
}
```

if you have more records, you can replace `if` with `while` and can iterate over `ResultSet`.

For the complete working example you can go through the [example here.](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)